# JAVA 8 - Stream() feature, not able to print the values by adding multiple filters

Tags: java, java-8, filtering, java-stream

Am trying to print the values from the `.stream()` via two `.filter()`. But the value is not printing.

With one `.filter()` am able to print the values.
Please find my code below.

```
listProducts.stream()
        .flatMap(listproducts -> listproducts.getProductAttr().stream())
        .flatMap(attr ->attr.getProductAttrValue().stream())
        .filter(av ->  av.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("source"))
        .filter(av -> av.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
        .forEachOrdered(av -> System.out.println(av.getValue()));
```

Comment: how can the string label equals to **source** and in the same time **description**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.filter(av -> Pattern.matches("(?i)source|description", av.getLabel()))
```

You are keeping only `"source"` strings (ignoring the case) after the first filtering.
The second `filter` kicks away the previous results.
You should build a composite boolean expression within one `filter`.
I suggest writing that simple regexp.*

<sup>*It can be improved by precompiling the pattern as @daniu's suggested.</sup>

Comment: And since this is essentially a loop, I'd suggest precompiling the pattern, ie `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)source|description")` and `.filter(av -> pattern.matcher(av.getLabel()).matches()`.

Comment: If not precompiling, you can use the simpler `.filter(av -> av.getLabel().matches("(?i)source|description"))`.

Answer (score 11):

No element of your `Stream` can pass the `Predicate`s passed to both of your `filter` calls, since `av.getLabel()` can't be equal to both "source" and "description" at the same time.

You can use a single filter instead:

```
.filter(av -> av.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("source") || 
              av.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
```